# Scanner keeps looping empty input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

for some reason I am having an issue where the scanner keeps getting no input and doesn't wait for the user to actually input anything, leading to an infinite loop. This is what my code looks like:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); //Takes user input
        System.out.println("Please enter your name");
        String input = "";
        if(kb.hasNextLine())
        {
            input = kb.nextLine();
        }
        while(input.isEmpty())
        {
           System.out.println("Please try again: ");
           if(kb.hasNextLine())
           input = kb.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println(input);
```

I know issues can occur if I was using kb.next() instead of nextLine because of the buffer, but this doesn't seem to be the case. I'm pretty confused and think this should be simple enough but unfortunately it's not. All it does for me is print "Please try again:" over and over without waiting for my input. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You get the message "over and over" because you have a `kb.hasNextLin()` check there which returns `false`. Which results in an endless `while()` loop. Simply remove the `hasNextLine()` checks.

Comment: Just initialize `input = null` it will work

Comment: @Progman unfortunately that didn't work. It instead throws an error "No line found" which usually happens if there's no input, but it's also not waiting for any input before it throws the error.

Comment: @SumitSingh Sadly that didn't make any difference, when I tried just your suggestion it threw an error on the while loop for calling .isEmpty on a null variable. I also tried removing the if(kb.hasNextLine()) from Progman's suggestion, but it also just gets a "No line found" error when it asks for the first input.

Comment: @N4V3H3114 How do you start your java application? It looks like you are not reading the user input from the keyboard but instead from a file.

Comment: Well though it worked for me. Let me try another way.

Comment: @Progman I start it with the main() function. And isn't System.in the way to read user input? I admit it would seem like it's trying to read from a file given the odd behavior. Maybe the issue is the compiler I'm using? I'm in Netbeans 12.0 using Gradle.

Comment: The code in the question seemed to work.